# How weak are the Van der Waals bonds? What is their contribution to the total mass of an object?

Tags: mass-energy, estimation, binding-energy, chemical-potential, graphene

We know that every binding energy can be expressed as a negative mass contribution to the total mass of the system. It is well known, for example, that composite nuclei have a “mass defect” when compared to the mass of their individual nucleons.

Although this is evident for nuclear binding energy, chemical binding energy becomes already too small for being taken into account – for example, “binding” together oxygen and hydrogen for creating $1\,\mathrm{kg}$ of water will result in a loss of only 150 ng.

How about even weaker forces? For example, graphene sheets in a piece of graphite are held together via van der Waals bonds / Casimir force.

How ridiculously little more would $1\,\mathrm{kg}$ of graphite weigh after all its individual graphene sheets become separated from each other?